# .net Compact reassign keyboard keys

Tags: .net, compact-framework

I have a Unitech PA690 Windows Mobile 6.5 Device that runs some simple software for work purposes. 
That apps been written in C#.NET Compact 3.5

What I've been trying to do is when the user presses the "#" key, somehow replace it with "." instead right away. Is this possible?

In the KeyDown event I tried:

```
TextBox.Text.Replace("#",".");
```

However, that always returns the cursor back to the start of the TextBox, so if the user keeps typing everything is all mixed up.

At the moment I'm using:

```
TextBox.Replace("#",".");
```

But on LostFocus, it works fine, but of course the "#" is still visible until the user leaves the TextBox.

[image: Unitech PA690]

Any help would be great, thanks.